# How to sum all amount paid by users

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I am finding it defficult to add up all amount paid by customers that ordered items

**Order Schema**

```js
const orderschema = new Mongoose.Schema({
  created: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
  amount: { type: Number, default: 0 }
  User: [{ type: Mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Users'}]
  ...
})
```

**Route**

```js
Get('/total-amount', total-amount)
```

**Controller**

```js
Exports.total-amount = () => {
  Order.find()...
}
```

I don't know what to add here to get the total amount made by all customers.

Using NodeJS and MongoDB.

Thank you for you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) in an aggregation stage like this:

- First `$group` all (without `_id` is to group all values)
- Then create field `total` which is the sum of al `amount`.
- And an optional stage, `$project` to output only `total` field.

```
db.order.aggregate({
  "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "total": {
      "$sum": "$amount"
    }
  }
},
{
  "$project": {
    "_id": 0
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9GtXgSzErrD)

To add into a controller using nodeJS and Mongoose you can use something like this piece of code:

```
Exports.total - amount = (req, res) => {
    Order.aggregate({
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "total": {
                "$sum": "$amount"
            }
        }
    }, {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0
        }
    }).then(response => {
        res.status(200).send(response)
    }).catch(e => res.status(400).send())
}
```

Note hoy the operation is done using your mongoose model (in this case `Order`). You are calling `aggregate` method in the same way you call `find` method for example: Instead of doing

```
yourModel.find()
```

Is

```
yourModel.aggregate()
```

And the response will be:

```
[
  {
    "total": 6
  }
]
```

So even you can update your controller to add a `if/else` block like this:

```
if(response[0].total)
  res.status(200).send(response[0].total)
else
  res.status(404).send()
```

Comment: Thank you @j.f I think I am still missing it. I am not familiar with aggregation. How do I add this to my controller.    Also, I did not define db but order model As Order                                             
  db.order.aggregate({
  "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "total": {
      "$sum": "$amount"
    }
  }
},
{
  "$project": {
    "_id": 0
  }
})

Comment: Thanks. It works. Accept my sincere appreciation